# PHP Notification Page - Table not displaying Results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, html-table, while-loop

I've created a notification script and I have a page called notificationCenter.php where the admin user can view ALL the notifications. It will display which users have read which notifications, when it was posted and who by. Everything works fine with it, the only issue is when I go onto the notificationCenter.php page to view all notifications, the table doesn't display the results. However I run an if statement to check if there are any results and I don't get any errors. Here's my code, I'm sure I've done something stupid but I can't see what it is, I'd really appreciate any help!.

```
//Get User ID
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

//Select * Notifications
$notQuery = $serviceConn->query("SELECT * FROM db759709251.notifications WHERE `not_viewedby` NOT LIKE '%$id%' ");

<h4>Nofication Center</h4>
        <?php if($notQuery->rowCount()) { ?>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">User</th>
                <th scope="col">Notification</th>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Viewed By</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
                while ($row = $notQuery->fetch()) {
                  $notid = $row['not_id'];
                  $notUser = $row['not_user'];
                  $notMsg = $row['not_msg'];
                  $notStatus = $row['not_status'];
                  $notDate = $row['not_date'];
                  $notViewedby = $row['not_viewedby'];

              ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="background-color: <?php echo $statusColour; ?>" data-label="Status"><?php echo $notStatus; ?></td>
                    <td data-label="User"><?php echo $notUser; ?></td>
                    <td data-label="Notification"><?php echo $notMsg; ?></td>
                    <td data-label="Date"><?php echo $notDate; ?></td>
                    <td data-label="Viewed By"><?php echo $notViewedby; ?></td>
                    <td data-label="">
                      <form action="" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="notificationID" value="<?php echo $notid; ?>" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="notificationBy" value="<?php echo $notViewedby; ?>">
                        <input type="submit" name="read" value="Dismiss!">
                      </form>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              <?php
                }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <?php } else { ?>
          <p>You currently have no notifications, please check back later.</p>
        <?php } ?>
```

Now obviously there is a lot of HTML in the middle for styling and layouts, but I didn't think it was important enough as it shouldn't have any effect on the output of the table. But as you can see the if statement SHOULD print that there are no notifications and to check back later, and it doesn't so in theory there should be records to display.

Comment: The table element exists in DOM?

Comment: "If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications. "

Comment: Sorry @JitendraKhatri what do you mean by DOM?

Comment: @BenSmith Check developer console and inspect you page. Is there any HTML exists for the same table you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not too sure how you mean but if i view the source code from the browser, the table appears but everything that should appear inside the while statement doesn't, so something isn't working on the while statement

Comment: @JitendraKhatri the developer console says theres no errors, no warnings nothing

Comment: @BenSmith use <pre>print_r($notQuery->fetch())</pre> to check what is in the object returned by this statement i.e. $row.

If there is something then while loop have to work or if null or "" then while loop will not work.

Comment: When i put that in, it doesn't print anything

Comment: @BenSmith put this at the top of your code to show errors `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`